# How to dispose the context variable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dispose, using-statement

I want to dispose the `devDB` context object in the below code.

```
private static void InitContainer()
{
     var devDB = new TestContext(constr);  
                 Container                 
                    .RegisterInstance<TestContext>(devDB)
                    .RegisterInstance<IRepository<User>>(new Repository<User>(devDB))
}

private static void CleanUp()
{
    if (Container != null)
    {
        Container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I tried a `using` statement, but the I receive the following error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

How can I dispose `devDB` correctly?

EDIT :

```
using (var devDB = new TestContext(constr))
            {

                var peopleService = new Peoplews();
                Container

                    .RegisterInstance<TestContext>(devDB)
                    .RegisterInstance<IRepository<User>>(new Repository<User>(devDB))
                    .RegisterInstance<IRepository<Role>>(new Repository<Role>(devDB))
                    .RegisterInstance<IRepository<Profile>>(new Repository<Profile>(devDB))
                    .RegisterInstance<IRepository<Application>>(new Repository<Application>(devDB))
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does "code is not running" mean? Can you please update your question with the error you're getting and when the error is happening?

Comment: getting "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

Comment: Also, are you using Entity Framework or something else?

Comment: entity framework only. @Sam

Comment: please tell me solution for dispose the devDB object.problem not yet resolved.

Comment: In the code at the bottom of your question, it looks like the DbContext is being disposed before even being used. Also, I think it's a bad idea to try to use the same DbContext across the entire lifecycle of an application. I think you should use DbContext as a unit of work for a single business operation.

Comment: can you provide sample on this how to use ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`using statements:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

```
using(var devDB = new TestContext(constr))
{
    // rest of your code
}
```

It will automatically `Dispose` your variable if it's `Disposable.`

Comment: i tried like that but database connection is not opening while declaring like that in my code.

Comment: i think OP has already tried `using` block because OP Says: `i tried as using statement but code is not running`

Comment: @user3106578 what do you mean by `but code is not running`, did you get any exception ?

Comment: getting  "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

Comment: @user3106578 are you sure you write your all code inside of `using` block ?

Comment: @user3106578, if you get that error message that means your `devDB` disposed before using in your statement `"Container.RegisterInstance<TestContext>(devDB).."` but I have no idea about how is that possible.You just creating it...

Comment: @user3106578: if you use using block and wrap up all your code inside using then that should get disposed once if it reaches the end of using block. as you are saying you get `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed` expcetion you should take care because it is getting disposed by some other statements before it reaches the end of using block, please share the code which you tried with using blcok.

Comment: Can please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `using` statement block to call the dispose method implicitly

```
 private static void InitContainer()
 {
       using(var devDB = new TestContext(constr))_
       {  
                 Container                 
                    .RegisterInstance<TestContext>(devDB)
                    .RegisterInstance<IRepository<User>>(new Repository<User>(devDB))
       }
  }
```

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler. The code example
>   earlier expands to the following code at compile time (note the extra
>   curly braces to create the limited scope for the object), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

The using block will be converted to try finally block like shown below. Also note the you wont be able to access context after being disposed.

```
{
        TestContext devDB  = new TestContext("Arial", 10.0f);
         try
         {
             devDB = new TestContext(constr);  
             Container                 
                .RegisterInstance<TestContext>(devDB)
                .RegisterInstance<IRepository<User>>(new Repository<User>(devDB))
         }
         finally
         {
            if (devDB != null)
               ((IDisposable)devDB).Dispose();
         }
  }
```

The code you have in question does not show any sign of using `context` out side the function, You can return the **data** instead of **query** from the method so that context is not longer required.

Comment: by using using statement getting "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection".

Comment: I tried above code same error i am getting .The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Comment: The code you have in question does not show any sign of using context out side the function, You can return the data instead of query from the method so that context is not longer required.

Comment: how i will avoid this EnsureLocalDisposalRule error raised by sonar?

Comment: How to dispose the devDB ?